# plm with time effects

Tags: r, plm

I'm trying to use the plm package in R for the first time.

I wish to estimate a pooling model with only time dummies, i.e. no unobserved heterogeneity.

I run a simple simple regression of the form:

```
plm(dep ~ x:y -1, data=data, index=c("panel_var", "time_var"), effect="time", model="pooling")
```

, where x is a continuous and y a categorical variable (and hence x:y the interaction). I added `-1` to the model to not include an intercept given that I wished to have time dummies.

When using `summary`, the model correctly informs me time size of the 'panel' and 'time' dimensions. However, it does not report the time dummies. By inspection I found out that it is because it does not include time dummies in the regression (running a simple `lm` regression without an intercept gives the same answer).

Given that `effect="time"` option does not add time dummies, what does it do?

I know that my desired model can be run with `lm` but I wanted to explicitly state the panel structure and use the `vcovSCC` covariance structure included in the plm package (although this is probably feasible also after running an `lm` regression).

Thanks for help!

Comment: a pooled OLS model has neither time nor individual effects. Maybe the package should issue an error message. You probably want a fixed effects model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pooled OLS model has neither time nor individual effects. Maybe the package should issue an error message. You probably want a fixed effects model, e. g.

```
data(Grunfeld, package="plm")
# estimate model with time effects
fe <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "time")

summary(fe)
# extract time effects
fixef(fe)
```